Office Excel - How to have a conditional format for X rows without having X formula
I have been working away all day on this. I am trying to get a list of values (cities) to be referenced by a range of user input values for conditional formatting.
I want the cell C2 through to C100 to check that the value does not exist in the list (Sheet1 B2:B125). The cells in the C column (other than the header) could be anything. The conditional formatting will be used as a form of visual validation. Showing the user that the value is in a predefined list, or isn't. I explain this bit, in case there is a better way than conditional formatting. Such as a VB Script for example.
Currently, I have chosen "use a formula to determine which cells to format" from within the conditional formatting section in home.
The formulas I have tried correctly work when I reference a specific field. Such as C2, C3, etc.
I really don't want to have to write this 100 times, and probably more when this gets to the end user. How can I have a single conditional format formula for a range starting at C2, to reference a city list on another tab/sheet.
 COUNTIF($C$2,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$125) = 1


COUNTIF(OFFSET($C$1,1,0),Sheet1!$B$2:$B$125) = 1


COUNTIF(C2,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$125) = 1 I think is the solution, you have the cell locked so it's only checking C2 for all the cells in C2:C100, by unlocking this cell it will validate for each.

Select C2:C100 and use =ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$125,0)) or a corrected version of what was suggested by Mark S. =COUNTIF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$125,C2)=1 (don't forget the leading equal sign and if there are duplicates in the lookup range, use >0 instead of =1).

@VBasic2008 adjusting my answer to account for duplicates, good catch. Also good alternative solution.

@Mark S. The 'alternative' formula is actually more efficient. Also, fix your formula in your answer: first comes the range, then the value.

In your conditional format formula, you have C2 locked ($C$2) which means that as the logic goes through each cell in C2:C100 it keeps asking, is C2 found in B2:B125? By unlocking the cell by removing the $, the logic will now go through each validating that cell's value against the list (as long as you apply the logic to C2 and each of the cells in the range).
Select the cells you want this logic applied to, starting with C2, and change you conditional format formula to be =COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$125,C2) >= 1. This should give you what you're looking for.
(edit: added >= 1 in case there are duplicates as VBasic2008 mentioned in their comment)
